# What is "action 17"?

Tags: logfiles

I was looking in `/var/log/syslog` for other reasons and i saw that it said:

```
May 23 06:25:54 raspberrypi rsyslogd0: action 'action 17' resumed (module 'builtin:ompipe') [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

then on the line just below it said:

```
May 23 06:25:54 raspberrypi rsyslogd-2359: action 'action 17' resumed (module 'builtin:ompipe') [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
```

what is the difference between these two and what do they mean?

I have searched for "action 17 on raspbian" and other things like that but found no helpful results.

Comment: Maybe related to [catch 22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[An answer can be found here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=152405)

I will simply cite from source [1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=152405):

> This is a bug in the rsyslog config from debian (which raspbian is
>   based off).
>
> It's something you can ignore, its just saying that the buffer
>   (/dev/xconsole) used by some (rare) applications is full.
>
> You can clear that buffer by reading from it (cat /dev/xconsole), but
>   then it'll fill up again over time. You can also remove a bit of
>   configuration to stop that buffer being used.
>
> As root edit the /etc/rsyslog.conf file and remove the following lines
>   from the bottom of the file.
>
> ```
> daemon.*;mail.*;\
>         news.err;\
>         *.=debug;*.=info;\
>         *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
> ```
>
> (you could also comment them out by putting a # at the start of the
>   lines)
>
> You can then restart the rsyslog service with CODE:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl restart rsyslog.service
> ```
>
> or reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for the Action 17 error message. Edit the file.

`sudo vi /etc/rsyslog.conf`

Go to the end of the file and split the lines as follows.

```
daemon.*; \ 
mail.*;\ 
news.err;\ 
*.=debug; \ 
*.=info;\ 
*.=notice; \ 
*.=warn |/dev/xconsole
```

`(control c) :wq!` - to exit if using vi !!!!

Restart the raspberry pi.
This allows `rsyslogd` to function properly.

Comment: Note the display of the above comment is incorrect. Each *.=blah \ should be on a separate line.